# Problems with ImageHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with calling ImageHandler..in asp i add imageurl like this:

```
ImageUrl= "~/DesktopModules/Philip.E1013542_skupine/Handler.ashx?id=62"
```

This shows picture in asp:image control. But i would like to retrieve id integer from query string like this:

.../Default.aspx?id=62

I tryed like this
`'<% "~/DesktopModules/Philip.E1013542_skupine/Handler.ashx?id=" & Eval("id") %>'`

but this doesn't calls handler at all..tryed with breakpoints and nothing.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/DesktopModules/Philip.E1013542_skupine/Handler.ashx?id=" + Request.QueryString("id")) %>" />
```